# EF Select records distinct by one field from Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, group-by, dynamic-linq

I need to "translate" this code sample:

```
using var db = new MyDbContext();
var simple_linq = db.USERS.GroupBy(u => u.id_employee).Select(u => u.FirstOrDefault()).ToList(); //it's worked fine for me
```

to same code with Dynamic LINQ. I've try:

```
var dynamic_linq = db.USERS.GroupBy(groupBy, "it").Select("it"); // but I need Dynamic LINQ
```

I receive a `USERS` objects in `dynamic_linq` (**very important** for me), but don't know how can I get unique `USERS`, don't know how can I use `FirstOrDefault()` function in Dynamic LINQ, don't know how can I convert my result to `List`. Don't know any other solution.

I've also try to use `DistinctBy()` from `MoreLinq` library, but it can not usage with dynamic expressions.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need your `Select` to be dynamic, or could you just put on a regular `Select`? Also, what if you do `Select("it.FirstOrDefault()")`? What dynamic LINQ package are you using?

Comment: @NetMage I can use a regular `Select`, dynamical must be `GroupBy`. When I've try to use `Select("it.FirstOrDefault()"` I've got an error. Using `System.Linq.Dynamic`.

Comment: @NetMage Error text: "No applicable aggregate method 'FirstOrDefault' exists".

Answer (score 1):

When using [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core), you should be able to use this code:

```cs
var users = new[] { new { id_employee = 1, name = "a"  }, new { id_employee = 1, name = "b"  } }.AsQueryable();

var simple_linq = users.GroupBy(u => u.id_employee).Select(u => u.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
simple_linq.Dump();

var dynamic_linq = users.GroupBy("id_employee", "it").Select("it.FirstOrDefault()");
dynamic_linq.Dump();
```

[image]

Comment: Thank's a lot. I will try use your code example and write down the results.